# JPanel Object Oriented Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, object-oriented-analysis

In my computer science class we are learning Java and we have come to the point in the course where we are learning about object orientation and how it is useful. We started a project a couple days ago, however instead of being tasked with basic object orientation, my teacher decided to challenge me and a few others by creating graphics right away without really teaching us.

We were tasked with creating a "Molecules" program that would accept an integer to create an array, and for each available section in the array, create a random x and y coordinate, as well as a size for the radius. Using these variables, a oval would be created. My teacher also told us that we should do this using either JFrame or JPanel, I chose JFrame.

In the code below you can see my attempt at this and where I am getting stuck. I have commented out the portion of setting the different colours because it is not important to this case.

```
/**
 * Name: Dylan Eisen
 * Date: May 1, 2017
 * Project: Object Oriented
 * Program: Molecules.java
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Molecules extends JFrame
{
    static Graphics g;
    public Molecules(Graphics g, int x, int y, int size)
    {
        super.paint(g);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of elements: ");
        int num = in.nextInt();
        int x = 20, y = 20, size = 20;
        object elements[] = new object[num];
        for(int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
        {
            x = (int)(Math.random()*1600);
            y = (int)(Math.random()*900);
            size = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            elements[i] = new object(g, x, y, size);
        }
        Molecules f = new Molecules(g, x, y, size);
        f.setSize(1600, 900);
        f.setVisible(true);
        //f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        f.setTitle("Molecules Program - Dylan Eisen"); 
    }
}
class object
{
    Graphics g;
    int x, y, size;
    public object(Graphics g, int x, int y, int size)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
    }
    void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        //g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval(x, y, size, size);
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me but also explain to me where I am going wrong, and how to fix this in the future, it would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

> If anyone could help me but also explain to me where I am going wrong, and how to fix this in the future, it would be really helpful!

The first problem is, you don't seem to understand how painting actually works in Swing.  Painting is a little bit of black magic, it seems like Swing "magically" calls the `paint` methods.  It's not overly complex, but I would highly recommend having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to better understand how the painting process works and how you can intergrate with it.

> My teacher also told us that we should do this using either JFrame or JPanel, I chose JFrame.

I would recommend using a `JPanel` as the base component, you can add this to whatever container you want later, which provides for a much more flexible solution.

As general recommendation, you should override the `paintComponent` of `JPanel`. If you find yourself overriding `paint`, you're probably doing something wrong.

You may also find that you have other issues with `JFrame`, as it's painting process is not double buffered and could also be interfered with by other components contained within the frame itself

A `JFrame` is actually a container for the `JRootPane`, which contains the `contentPane`, `JMenuBar` and `glassPane`

[image: JFrame Layers]

When you override `paint` of `JFrame`, the other components can paint over your stuff without you been notified (they can can be painted independently)

Generally speaking, a `Graphics` context is a abstract concept of a series of routines which can generate a image.  Swing passes the `Graphics` context used to paint the window through the `paint` methods, you should never maintain a reference to this context and you should only use it when the `paint` method is called.  This means that your `object` class won't need a constructor which needs a `Graphics` context, it should only ever be painted within the context of a paint method/cycle.

`object` is a really, really bad name of a class, as Java defines a `Object` class of it's own, which all other classes extended from by default (if they don't specify a parent class)

I'd also highly recommend that you take a look at [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html).  It will make it easier for other people to read your code and for other people to read yours